# Trying to edit WordPress CSS for site but cant find CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the left hand menu color from dark grey to white on this page:
http://bilatlures.com/my-account/

But I cannot find the color in the back end, so I tried using the FTP server and I was going to download the CSS and change it manually and re-upload it, but I cant find it.

How do I find it?

Comment: Inspect the element with `Firebug` or `Chrome` developer tools, and see where it's coming from.

Comment: Did you follow all the paths in the source code? There are clearly a number of css files in the `themes` and `plugins` folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your FTP, just add :

```
.widget-container h3.widget-title {
  color: #fff;
}
```

In the last line of :

```
/wp-content/themes/vizio/style.css
```

In the wordpress admin, maybe on `Appearance > Theme Options`

Comment: that i just an empty CSS file, I tries using source code to find where the .css is hiding, all I need to change is the color in the css from #666 to #fff

Comment: You don't need to find the property to do that, go in /wp-content/themes/vizio/style.css and place all CSS rules you want.

Comment: I didnt down vote, it was someone else, But I already tried that in the back end, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Which element is concerned ?

Comment: Ok so if you go into the source code, high light any of the dark grey words, find in the CSS that dark grey color. it's color:#333; I need to change that to #fff. I actually found the CSS file where it's held. It;s called theme-woocommerce-styles.css and I downloaded it, changed it to #fff; uploaded it, but it still isn't fixed.. :S Edit I just checked the source code and I can see my edit to the file, but the color:fff; is crossed out. Why?

Comment: Edited my answer. And check if a cache plugin is running on your WP (turn off for a moment if so).

Comment: It didn't work, I'm still trying by editing the files and uploading the to the server but no changes happen.

Comment: OK! got it to work by editing the CSS manually. you can have the answer, you helped me in a way.

Answer (score -1):

After viewing your source, it looks like there are some StyleSheets in the `/wp-content/themes/` and `/wp-content/plugins/` directories of your site.

Comment: Not sure why every single answer in this question was just downvoted, including the question itself...